# Retrieve only file from GET folder request to Box.com

Tags: rest, box-api

I need retrieve only file from a GET request to Box.com.

Problem is the follow...
I have a Panel where I show the files contents in a folder.
Currently I get all the content and I keep only the elements that have type equals to "file".

Now I need to paginate the results. I use the Box API to get an offset of result, in this way:

```
GET https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0/items?limit=2&offset=1
Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN
```

I ask for the fist 2 elements. But is obviously that if the first 2 elements is both folder, my panel will show zero elements.

Is there a way to make a GET request specifying the type of the elements? something like this:

```
GET https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0/items?limit=2&offset=1&type=file
Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to probably use the Search API:  http://developers.box.com/docs/#search

It lets you specify type=file and get only files.  However it goes into all the sub-directories recursively, so it may not provide exactly what you are looking for.  If you are looking for only the top-level directory and files-only, then you'll have to do the filtering on your side after the API response. Use GET ./folders//items and paginate through all the items, throwing away all the type=folders items.

Comment: If I use the Search API I need to create a complex query for retrieve ALL the FILEs on a specified folder, rigth? but I lost the order that the user set on his box account (It seems that when you get the folder content the order is the same of the online account, rigth?)

Comment: Anyway... this answer means that there's no way to retrieve only files from the common `GET https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0/items`?

Comment: Y, there's not a way to do filtering of the GET /folders/<id>/items right now. It's something we've contemplated, but most clients have been able to handle the filtering so far.

Comment: I'm trying to resolve this issue with search API... But I can't find a solution in the official docs. 'https://....../search?query=*&type=file'  but this don't word for get all the files... What I have to use instead the *?

Comment: Actually the order of the items is not the same as what the user has set.  API ordering of items is it's own thing, specified in the "order" JSON